# Jquery BUG -  animation problem on mouse out

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a div on a page with the following properties:

```
  div
  {
    width:100px;
    background:#0000ff;
    height:100px;
  }
```

I am animating the `border-radius` of the div on mouse hover event. The animation works fine when the mouse is entering, but the animation stops working when the mouse is coming out of the DIV. You can see the [LIVE CODE ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/codingfreak/9LnTE/). Here when you will enter the div, the border-radius is smoothly getting animated, **but when the mouse is coming out, the animation doesnt work and the border-radius changes instantaneously**.

Where is the problem with the code?

And one more thing, **If I move the mouse In-and-Out on the div too fast, and then wait, the div-animation is going on, it doesn't stop.**

The link to the [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/codingfreak/9LnTE/)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, if you do `$('div').animate({//change border}, function(){//change border again});` the same thing happens. So the mouse events are not the cause.

Comment: @Decko - you mean there is a bug in Jquery?

Comment: Freak I think so, if you animate the width instead it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in **Chrome** this worked for me ... it seems that the browser parses `-webkit` and after the animation is complete jQuery cannot get the new values

so this is the code that worked for me:

```
animateCorners = function(event) {

    r = (event.type=='mouseenter' ? 40 : 0);
    style = {
        'border-top-left-radius': r,
        'border-top-right-radius': r,
        'border-bottom-right-radius': r,
        'border-bottom-left-radius': r
    };
    $(this).stop().animate(
        style
    , 1000, function(){
        $(this).css(style);
    });

}
$('div').hover(
    animateCorners,
    animateCorners
);
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LnTE/24/)

Comment: GREAT JOB. Worked as i wanted.

Comment: I dont have Opera installed on my PC. So could you please modify the answer to support Opera also?

Answer (score 0):

Is this just in Firefox?

Try changing:

```
'-moz-border-radius':'0',
```

to:

```
'MozBorderRadiusTopleft': '0',
'MozBorderRadiusTopright': '0',       
'MozBorderRadiusBottomleft': '0',
'MozBorderRadiusBottomright': '0'
```

That works fine for me in Firefox 3.6

Answer (score 0):

If you change your script to this:

```
$('div').hover(
    function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({
                'border-radius':'40px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'40px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'40px'
            }
            , 1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({
                'border-radius':'10px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'10px'
            }
            , 1000);
    }
);
```

you will notice that a mouse-out animation does occur, but starts from the original radius, rather than the one you changed it to during the mouse-over script.

However, I'm not sure if this is the correct behaviour of jQuery or not.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
    'border-radius':'40px',
    '-moz-border-radius':'40px',
    '-webkit-border-radius':'40px'
```

with

```
    'border-top-left-radius': '40px',
    'border-top-right-radius': '40px',
    'border-bottom-right-radius': '40px',
    'border-bottom-left-radius': '40px',
    'MozBorderRadiusTopleft': '40px',
    'MozBorderRadiusTopright': '40px',
    'MozBorderRadiusBottomleft': '40px',
    'MozBorderRadiusBottomright': '40px',
    'WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius': '40px',
    'WebkitBorderTopRightRadius': '40px',
    'WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius': '40px',
    'WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius': '40px',
```

too see it done ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/EUBwG/2/

tested on : **Firefox 4**, **Firefox 3.6**, **Chrome**

Answer (score 0):

this hover-out function works for me:

```
     function () {
        $(this).animate({
           'border-top-left-radius' : '0px',
           'border-top-right-radius' : '0px',
           'border-bottom-left-radius' : '0px',
           'border-bottom-right-radius' : '0px',
           '-webkit-border-top-left-radius' : '0px',
           '-webkit-border-top-right-radius' : '0px',
           '-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius' : '0px',
           '-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius' : '0px',
           '-moz-border-radius-topleft' : '0px',
           '-moz-border-radius-topright' : '0px',
           '-moz-border-radius-bottomleft' : '0px',
           '-moz-border-radius-bottomright' : '0px'
        }, 1000);
```

it worked in firefox 4, ie9 and some old version of chrome.

Comment: The problem is not the pixel, as you can see 
                'border-radius':'0px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'0px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'0px'
doesn't work. The problem is the different interpretation of border-radius and border-top-left-radius border-top-right-radius border-bottom-left-radius border-bottom-right-radius

Comment: yes okay. but when you leave out the px then it wouldn't work anyway ;) the other thing is, of course, important, too

Comment: I dont know what browser are you talking about, but this http://jsfiddle.net/EUBwG/2/ works even if he has not the 'px', just sayin'

Comment: okay, you are right. there must have been something else wrong during my tests. the "px" doesn't have to do anything with it. sorry for the mistake

Answer (score -1):

To get it to work in Chrome and Firefox, the corners have to be animated separately for MozBorderRadius and WebkitBorderRadius:

See http://jsfiddle.net/9LnTE/34/

```
$('div').hover(
    function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({
                'border-radius':'40px',
                '-moz-border-radius':'40px',
                '-webkit-border-radius':'40px'
            }
            , 1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this)
            .animate({
                'border-radius':'0',
                'MozBorderRadiusTopleft': '0',
                'MozBorderRadiusTopright': '0',       
                'MozBorderRadiusBottomleft': '0',
                'MozBorderRadiusBottomright': '0',
                'WebkitBorderTopLeftRadius': '0', 
                'WebkitBorderTopRightRadius': '0', 
                'WebkitBorderBottomLeftRadius': '0', 
                'WebkitBorderBottomRightRadius': '0',
            }
            , 1000);
    }
);
```

Comment: A good reminder to test in all current versions of a browser, thanks.